# Is long range entanglement detectable with k-local operators?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Given a state $\psi \in H_1\otimes H_2\otimes ... H_n$, and there is long range entanglement, is it possible to certify this by only using k-local operators where $k < n$?

To make it concrete but less general, an example is asking if the GHZ state, $\vert\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert 00..0\rangle + \vert 11..1\rangle)$ and some less entangled state are indistinguishable if I am allowed to measure only using operators that are of the form, $O_{12}, O_{23}...$ and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By any measurement on $n-1$ sites, the GHZ state 
$$
|0,0,\dots,0\rangle+|1,1,\dots,1\rangle
$$
and the state 
$$
|0,0,\dots,0\rangle-|1,1,\dots,1\rangle
$$
are indistinguishable, as they have the same $n-1$-site reduced density matrix.

So the answer to your question is **No**.

Comment: Just to add on, your alternate state is also maximally entangled. Would you be able to comment on the case of whether k-local operators can also distinguish between the GHZ state and one with entanglement, say over s sites and $k<s$?

Comment: @user1936752 If you don't restrict to pure state (which seems contrived), then there is a separable state with the same $n-1$ site reduced density matrices.

Comment: Yes, but I am allowed to use multiple k-local operators. For it to be indistinguishable, every k-local operator must produce the same measurements. The claim you make, is it still true if I have many operators like $O_{1..k}, O_{2..k+1}...O_{n-k+1..n}$?

Comment: Yes, the 50-50 mixture of |0,0...> and |1,1,...> is indistinguishable from the GHZ for *all* n-1 site measurements.