# $k$-local Hamiltonian with long range entangled ground states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, many-body, ground-state

Is it possible, and if yes, is there a relatively simple example of a Hamiltonian that only has k-local terms but its ground state *always* has entanglement beyond $k$ sites?

For instance if $H = H_{AB} +H_{BC} +H_{CA}$, can one show an example where the ground state is always entangled in $A,B$ and $C$?

If this is impossible, could someone explain how to prove it?

Following the comments, I wrote a program that generated random 2-local Hermitian operators, which I tensored with the $n-2$ identity operators. I then summed to make a Hamiltonian on n-qubits with only 2-local terms. Indeed, for $n=3$, the ground state of this Hamiltonian usually shows entanglement between the first and the third qubit.

Based on this [question and answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453544/is-long-range-entanglement-detectable-with-k-local-operators), I initially thought that k-local Hamiltonians would not have ground states with $k+1$ site entanglement. This statement is clearly false.

What I am still not sure of:

1. For every state that is entangled in $k+1$ sites, does there exist a state that is entangled in only $k$ or fewer sites that has the same reduced $k$-site statistics? Or does this depend on the state itself e.g. the GHZ state does but maybe other entangled states don't?
2. If the answer to 1) is always yes, is there not a contradiction with the fact that the ground state of a 2-local Hamiltonian is 3-site entangled? In other words, should there not exist an at most 2-site entangled state that is indistinguishable for this Hamiltonian (so has the same energy as the ground state) from the 3-site entangled ground state that we found?

Comment: How many examples did you check?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, I have edited the question to add an example - I realize my question was also unclear before but it's fixed now.

Comment: Again, how many examples on 3 qubits did you try?  I'd say any random Hamiltonian is an example for what you want.  Or take the Ising ferromagnet with a very small transverse field.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch could you look at the edited question? I think it is closely connected to another of my questions that you answered. Thank you

Comment: If the ground state is unique, it is the only state with those RDMs.  And for a generic Hamiltonian, the GS will be unique.  Whether this property is preserved in the thermodynamic limit is a different question, but it is not what you are asking.